# Open XML SDK: How to get a valid Word document for WordprocessingDocument.Open

Tags: c#, openxml

For unit testing purposes, I would like to generate some sample data to be stored as a stream in the `dataToImport` variable in the following statement:

```
WordprocessingDocument.Open(dataToImport, false);
```

Does anyone know how to create a decent set of sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially use something like the following:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wpd = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, false) 
{
    wpd.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(GenerateParagraph(...text ...);
}


private Paragraph GenerateParagraph(string input) 
{
    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
    Run run1 = new Run();
    Break break1 = new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page };
    Text txt = new Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
    txt.Text = input;
    run1.Append(break1);
    run1.Append(txt);
    paragraph1.Append(run1);
    return paragraph1;

}
```

The value of the `...text...` itself could come from any file using `FileInputStream` objects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks dude.  I'll give this a go.  I'm sure it will work though.